# Using UpdateChildValues to delete from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete data from several locations in the Firebase database simultaneously.

The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data) state:

> "The simplest way to delete data is to call removeValue on a reference to the location of that data.  You can also delete by specifying nil as the value for another write operation such as setValue or updateChildValues. You can use this technique with updateChildValues to delete multiple children in a single API call."

My code is

```
let childUpdates = [path1 : nil,
                    path2 : nil,
                    path3 : nil,
                    path4 : nil]

    ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

All four paths are strings, but I get an error:

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context."

I'd assume this occurs because of the nil values, since if I replace nil with anything else (such as an Int) the error disappears.

What is the correct way to use updateChildValues to delete data from Firebase? We want it to work in a similar way to the removeValue() function in Firebase. The reason we would prefer to do this is because it can remove from multiple places in one call.

Comment: As they said, I think the method should be `updateChildValues(values: [AnyHashable : Any?])` to allow `nil`. Thanks for asking!!! I found the answer from @Jay

Answer (score 54, accepted):

So the issue here is that

```
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

requires a [String: AnyObject!] parameter to updateChildValues, and AnyObject! cannot be a nil (i.e. you can't use AnyObject? which is an optional that could be nil)

However, you can do this

```
let childUpdates = [path1 : NSNull(),
                    path2 : NSNull(),
                    path3 : NSNull(),
                    path4 : NSNull()]
```

Because AnyObject! is now an NSNull() object (not nil), and Firebase knows that NSNull is a nil value.

**Edit**

You can expand on this to also do multi-location updates. Suppose you have a structure

```
items
   item_0
      item_name: "some item 0"
   item_1
      item_name: "some item 1"
```

and you want update both item names. Here's the swift code.

```
func updateMultipleValues() {
    let path0 = "items/item_0/item_name"
    let path1 = "items/item_1/item_name"

    let childUpdates = [ path0: "Hello",
                         path1: "World"
    ]

    self.ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates) //self.ref points to my firebase
}
```

and the result is

```
items
   item_0
      item_name: "Hello"
   item_1
      item_name: "World"
```

Comment: you save my day

Comment: Thanks so much! This definitely needs to be in the Firebase documentation, so frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is coming from the first line you've provided. You need to specify the type of dictionary. So change it to

```
let childUpdates: [String : AnyObject?] = [path1: nil, path2: nil,...]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. The expected type for the dictionary is [NSObject: AnyObject]. If the dictionary is not that type, the updateChildValues function will give an error. We have tried changing the paths to NSObjects, but it still complains with the nil value on AnyObject?. It seems like we are unable to put nil values in, but they say in their docs that we can so there may be a way that we just have not figured out.

Comment: I think if you use empty strings `""` Firebase will remove it. try that.

Comment: It just changes the value at the path to an empty string

Comment: then i think you should go down the removeValue path rather than trying to do what you're doing.