# Firebase Real Time Database data saving strategy

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am looking into how Firebase RealTime Database stores values. For example: if the data type is number and instead of a number I store `null`, does it allocate 1 byte or 8 byte? I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Second concern is: I am sending a `geolocation` point. In the database I want to check if it is cast to `float` or `geopoints` data type. How can I check?

Comment: Firebase does not support *storing* a 'Null', and if you set a nodes value to Null (nil) it will be removed. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462074/using-updatechildvalues-to-delete-from-firebase/38466959#38466959) on how to remove multiple nodes at one time using NSNull (ObjC)

Answer (score 6):

The Firebase Realtime Database is just a JSON tree. You can imagine it as being  a large Text file that contains a very large String (and that string is your database). Text files don't really parse through data types, which means that if you store `null`, it sums up **4 bytes** (1 byte per character) and storing the number `4` for example will be allocating **1 byte**.

Answering the second question: The only data types supported by the Firebase Realtime Database (Android) are:

1. String
2. Long
3. Double
4. Boolean
5. Maps
6. Lists

That means that your Geolocation will be cast to Double.

Edit: ObjC/Swift data supported data types are

```
NSString
NSNumber
NSDictionary
NSArray
```

Comment: [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) on the other hand has a wider variety of [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) including Geographical points. You might want to have a look at it.

Comment: Good answer! As a side note, Firebase does not support storing a 'Null' data type. i.e. every key must have a value of one of the above mentioned ones - a value cannot be nil/null and if it is, the node will be removed.